# Solaris 10 - dbx dump not showing local variables

Tags: solaris-10, dbx

I'm a Windows developer who uses WinDbg regularly and fairly easily. I got a Solaris 10.2 core file to analyze using dbx. where (dbx) displayed the stack and I could locate the .so that had the implementation. As dump (dbx) showed no results (local vars), I used file (os) command which said the binary was stripped. I located best possible matching unstripped .so version and verified it using file command.
As the process that had crashed was currently running again, I did not want to stop it. So, I copied all the binaries to a new location and then copied over the unstripped .so. When I tried to open the core now, it complained that core was older than the binary, use touch. So, I copied the core to a new location and then dbx opened it with no complains.
Still, dump (dbx) shows no results. I tried moving up & down in frames but dump is always mute.
How would I know if the unstripped version did not match? How to check that symbols are loaded?

Comment: what is the architecture? amd64?

Comment: @horsh Thank for checking this. It was 64 bit.